# Null parameters to php class methods

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I have a method in a php class that is made it to get data from database. This method has 3 parameters and the idea is to query database considering that 1, 2 or the 3 of these parameters are not null. Below is the method described above:

```
public function resultSearch($city = null, $price = null, $nr_dhomash = null){
        $db = new Database;
        $stmt = "";

        if ($city != null && $price != null && $nr_dhomash !=null) {
            $query = "Select * from postim where qyteti = :q and price <= :p and nr_dhoma=:n";
            $stmt = $db->connect()->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(":q", $qyteti);
            $stmt->bindParam(":p", $price);
            $stmt->bindParam(":n", $nr_dhomash);
        }else if ($city != null && $price !=null) {
            $query = "Select * from postim where qyteti=:q and price <= :p";
            $stmt = $db->connect()->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(":q", $qyteti);
            $stmt->bindParam(":p", $price);
        }else if ($city != null && $nr_dhomash !=null) {
            $query = "Select * from postim where qyteti=:q and nr_dhoma=:n";
            $stmt = $db->connect()->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(":q", $qyteti);
            $stmt->bindParam(":n", $nr_dhomash);
        }else if ($price != null && $nr_dhomash !=null) {
            $query = "Select * from postim where price <= :p and nr_dhoma=:n";
            $stmt = $db->connect()->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(":p", $price);
            $stmt->bindParam(":n", $nr_dhomash);
        }else if ($city != null) {
            $query = "Select * from postim where qyteti=:q";
            $stmt = $db->connect()->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(":q", $city);
        }else if($price != null){
            $query = "Select * from postim where price <= :p";
            $stmt = $db->connect()->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(":p", $price);
        }else if ($nr_dhomash != null) {
            $query = "Select * from postim where nr_dhoma=:n";
            $stmt = $db->connect()->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(":n", $nr_dhomash);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
```

I don't know why this method doesn't work properly if 2 or all parameters are not null. Can someone help?

Comment: What is the problem? what did you get wrong?

Comment: This method only works if one parameter is not null, if there are 2 parameters not null or all 3 parameters not null, it returns null or it will work as if only one parameter is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this can be simplified to:

```
public function resultSearch($city = null, $price = null, $nr_dhomash = null){
    $db = new Database;
    $stmt = "";
    $where = [];
    $params = [];

    if ($city != null) {
        $where[] = 'qyteti = ?';
        $params[] = $city;
    }

    if ($price != null) {
        $where[] = 'price <= ?';
        $params[] = $price;
    }

    if ($nr_dhomash != null) {
        $where[] = 'nr_dhoma = ?';
        $params[] = $nr_dhomash;
    }

    $query = "Select * from postim";
    if ($where) {
        $query .= ' where ' . implode(' and ', $where);
    }
    $stmt = $db->connect()->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($params);

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: That worked, is a great solution, thank you u_mulder!